# Show that $x^n + x + 3$ is irreducible for all $n \geq 2.$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

So first of all, I used the following from my lecture notes:

If $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is primitive (gcd of all the coefficients is 1) - $f$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x] \Leftrightarrow$ f irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

So now I only have to show that $f_n = x^n + x + 3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for all $n \geq 2. $

Is there a pattern I should be appealing to in some way?

Comment: What if $p/q$ is a root of $f_n$ in lowest terms, and you multiply the equation $f_n(p/q)=0$ by $q^n$ on both sides? Then $q$ must divide $p^n$, and $p$ must divide $3q^n$. Makes sense?

Comment: You version of Eisenstein criterion is false. It would imply all monic polynomials in $\mathbf Z[x]$ are irreducible.

Comment: @HowDoIMath: not having a root does not mean being irreducible, except if $n=2,3$.

Comment: @Bernard good lord! Thank you, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If we had a decomposition in $\mathbb Z[x]$  $$x^n + x + 3=p(x)\cdot q(x)=(x^a+\dots+c_a)\cdot(x^b+\dots+d_b)$$ we would deduce $c_a\cdot d_b=3$ so that we would have, maybe after renaming the factors, $c_a=\pm 1$ (and of course $d_b=\pm 3$).
This means that for the (complex!) zeros $z_i$ of $p(x)$ we would have $\prod |z_i|=1$, so that at least one of those zeros, say $z_1$, must satisfy $|z_1|\leq 1$.
But then, since  $z_1$ is also  a zero of our original polynomial:  $z_1^n+z_1+3=0$.
This is clearly impossible since $|z_1^n+z_1|\leq |z_1|^n+|z_1|\leq 2$.

This contradiction shows that $x^n + x + 3$ is actually irreducible.

**Edit**
I now realize that the same method proves that $x^n + x + p$ and $x^n + x - p$ are irreducible for any prime integer  $p\geq 3$.

Comment: I have always been impressed by the effectiveness of this technique, which for more difficult applications often requires Rouché's theorem.  Is there a similar kind of yoga that works over fields besides $\mathbb{C}$, I wonder?

Comment: Very neat! I was expecting some mess...

Comment: Is this a known technique? It's slick and I would like to find more examples so I can understand it and add it to my "toolbox."

Comment: I used to give these kinds of results as exercises in courses on field theory. I probably read about these techniques in standard collections of exercises preparing to entrance in élite French schools, like Polytechnique or Ecole Normale Supérieure. The level is somewhat like that of Prelims or Quals in the USA. That said, I don't know if these tricks have been integrated in a satisfyingly theoretical general framework, which would be more to my taste than clever but *ad hoc* manipulations.

Comment: Just noticed the edit. That's definitely one to note down for my exam!

Answer (score 4):

This can be also shown by referring to irreducibility criterion as given by Osada, see for example Theorem 2.2.7 in Prasolov's book [Polynomials](https://books.google.cz/books/about/Polynomials.html?id=b1a7ye_EjZwC&redir_esc=y):

> Let $f(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}x\pm p$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, where $p$ is a prime. If $p>1+|a_1|+\dots+|a_{n-1}|$, then $f$ is irreducible.

Since $3>1+1$, the irreducibility follows.