# Study the irreducible of polynomial $P(X) = X^n + X + p$, with $p$ be a prime number and $n$ an integer $\geq 2$.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n$ an integer $\geq 2$. We set $P(X) = X^n + X + p.$

**Problem**

a) We assume $p \neq  2$ or $n$ even. Show that $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

b) We assume $p = 2$ and $n$ odd. Show that we have $P (X) = (X + 1) Q (X)$ with
$Q$ irreducible on $\mathbb{Q}$.

**My effort:**

a) $P\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is primitive then $P$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X] \Leftrightarrow$ P irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

*If $p \neq  2$*

> If we had a decomposition in $\mathbb Z[X]$  $P(X)=P_1(X)\cdot P_2(X)=(X^{n_1}+\dots+a)\cdot(X^{n_2}+\dots+b)$ we would deduce $a\cdot b=p$ so without losing generality, we can suppose that $a=\pm 1$. This means that for the complex zeros $z_i$ of $P_{1}(x)$ we would have $\prod_{i=1}^{n_1}|z_i|=1$, so that at least one of those zeros, say $z$, must satisfy $|z|\leq 1$.
> But then, since  $z$ is also  a zero of polynomial $P$:  $z^n+z+p=0$. This is clearly impossible since $p=|z^n+z|\leq |z|^n+|z|\leq 2$.  This contradiction shows that $X^n + X + p$ is actually irreducible.

*If $n$ even*

> I don't have an idea!!

b)  $P (X) = X^n + X+2 $ Then $-1$ is zeros of $P$, so we have  $P (X) = (X + 1) Q (X)$ with $Q=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{(-1)^kX^k +2}$. But I can't show that $Q$ is irreducible on $\mathbb{Q}$.

An idea please.

Comment: See Georges proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198973/show-that-xn-x-3-is-irreducible-for-all-n-geq-2). As he says, it works for every prime $p\ge 3$. You have copied the proof, it seems. Also Sil gives a proof, which works both for $n$ odd and $n$ even.